# How to "shuffle" includes from twig

Tags: symfony, twig

I have a base template that includes multiple sub-templates and the code runs something like this:

```
<ul class="row portfolio list-unstyled mt-3 lightbox" id="grid">
                <!-- summary section -->
                {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\ReadController::summary')) }}
                {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\BookController::random', {num: 3})) }}
                {{ render(controller('App\\Controller\\WikiController::random')) }}

</ul><!-- / portfolio row -->
```

As can be seen, these "items" appear in a fixed order:`summary` goes first, then 3 `random` and then one `random`.

What I intend to do is to "shuffle" these items (in the above code snippet, there will be 5 items) so that the order is different in each refresh to give the end user some variation.

Is this possible to do in Twig?

**UPDATE**

I used @hcoat method and it is working. Will try the `shuffle` filter later.

Comment: Why don't you just do it in the controller? Anyway you could do something like `{% set items = [ render(...), render(...), render(...), ] %}` and then shuffle them with this [extension](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html)

Comment: Like DarBee said, you should do it in the controller, then loop through your array in twig...

Comment: If I am to do that in one controller, that controller will become very big and the items are from different controllers. Will try the extension method later. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

As suggested to you in the comments above you can use the [`Array Extension`](http://twig-extensions.readthedocs.io/en/latest/array.html) or send it through a controller. I think having a controller that sends in the random list is the way to go.

However, sometimes it is useful to randomize a list with standard twig and in such cases you can do something like the following:

```
// Path and pram Array, pass empty hash if no params
{% set arr = [
  ["App\\Controller\\ReadController::summary", {}],
  ["App\\Controller\\BookController::random", {'num': 3}],
  ["App\\Controller\\WikiController::random", {}]
] %}
// create a list and merge arr array with random key
{% set list = {} %}
{% for item in arr %}
    // There is a bug in some twig verions
    // so concat a letter to ensure random key works
    {% set list = list|merge({ (random()~'a'):(item) }) %}
{% endfor %}
// sort the list by the random key and render the output
{% for key in list|keys|sort %}
    {{ render(controller(list[key][0], list[key][1])) }}
{% endfor %}
```

Now the sub-templates will be rendered in a random order.